# Get reaction time on button click stm32 board

Tags: c, stm32, stm32f4discovery

I'm trying to make a reaction time game on an stm32 board in C. I'm not sure how to return the exact reaction time, at the moment I made a loop which adds 50ms each time it loops, without getting interrupted.

```
if ((GPIOA->IDR & USER_GPIO_PIN) != 0x0)
{
   //code
}
```

So, when you click the button (USER_GPIO_PIN) it should break the loop and return an exact reaction time number (not sure how to do this) or an estimate with

```
LCD_GLASS_DisplayString((uint8_t*)"text");
```

So is there any function to get the time difference between presses of the button?

Also, I tried adding a random delay to make the game more enjoyable (after a certain delay the led light flashes and you have to press the button), but the random function I tried, doesn't seem to work.

```
srand(time(NULL));
uint32_t randomDelay = rand();
```

Comment: Only call `srand` once, at the start of your program.

Comment: As you are looking for human reaction times, `clock()` might be appropriate. Mark the start time, subtract that from the `clock()` value when the button is pressed. For the actual elapsed time see the man page and `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.

Comment: Thanks Weather Vane :)

Comment: There are a couple general purpose hardware timers, a Real Time Clock, and the system clock. You can use any of them.

Comment: What libraries do you use in development?

Answer (score 0):

The random functionality in software is just a table with a lot of random numbers. The srand function dictates where in the table you will begin to look.

In other words you will need a "random" number to begin with (**aka seed**), in order to get the process started. One way to derive this seed is to look at the current time as you did. If this did not work I would look at how srand is used (remember it should only be used once in the initialization) and also **what the function time(NULL) returns**.

The stm32 (and most other MCU) does have its **own random generator** built into the HW itself. This functionality becomes available by configuring a defined set of HW registers. ST Microelectronics is kind enough to supply us with both example code and a HAL library bundled together called "**STM32Cube**" that you can use as a guideline when configuring this. For the stm32f7 series, please see the file **stm32f7xx_hal_rng.c**.

Answer (score 0):

> So, when you click the button (USER_GPIO_PIN) it should break the loop and return an exact reaction time number (not sure how to do this)

The 'clean' way to do this is to attach an `EXTI` interrupt to your button GPIO pin to trigger on the appropriate edge that matches your button 'down' transition.

When you light the LED, record the current value of a timer. When you get the EXTI interrupt, subtract the new timer value from the old and set a variable to tell your main loop to wake up and do something. Systick is the easiest timer to use for this.

> srand(time(NULL));

Not going to work unless you have a backed up RTC that's keeping real-time between resets and a library that's integrating with that.

If you want to seed a PRNG on the STM32 then sample some external randomness like the bottom bits of the temperature/voltage sensor ADC inputs or a floating pin. Better still, use the hardware RNG.